# Carrierwave mongoid upload. Getting an undefined method `empty?' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000109968c50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, http-upload

I'm trying to upload an image file to my rails server, but I keep hitting a wall.

This is my form `themed_controller/new` ,

```
= form_for(@campaign, validate: true, :html => {:multipart => true}) do
        .form-group
            %label.col-sm-3.control-label
                Campaign Name
            .col-sm-6
                %input#title.form-input{ name: "@campaign[campaign_title]", placeholder: "Campaign Title",  required: "", type: "text", value: ""}/
        .form-group
            %label.col-sm-3.control-label
                Campaign Description
            .col-sm-6
                %textarea.form-input{ name: "@campaign[campaign_description]", placeholder: "Campaign Description",  required: "", value: ""}

        .form-group
            %label.col-sm-3.control-label
                Pick stories
            .col-sm-6
                %select#themed_campaign_live_story_ids{name: "@campaign[live_story_ids][]", :multiple => true,  :required=> true, value: []}
                -# = f.select 'live_story_ids[]', [], :multiple => true
        #date-range
            .form-group#valid-from
                %label.col-sm-3.control-label
                    Campaign runs from
                .col-sm-6
                    %input.form-input#themed_campaign_valid_from{ name: "@campaign[valid_from]",:class => 'jquery-ui-date valid-from',  :data => {:provide =>"datepicker", :behaviour => "datepicker"},  required: "", type: "text", value: ""}/

            .form-group#valid-till
                %label.col-sm-3.control-label
                    Campaign runs till
                .col-sm-6
                    %input.form-input#themed_campaign_valid_till{ name: "@campaign[valid_till]",:class => 'jquery-ui-date valid-till',  :data => {:provide =>"datepicker", :behaviour => "datepicker"},  required: "", type: "text", value: ""}/
        .form-group#valid-till
            %label.col-sm-3.control-label
                Upload cover (1280x350)
            .col-sm-6
                -#upload-image.btn.btn-medium.btn-green{ :data => {:url => "/campaign/upload"} }

                #upload-image
                    %input#image_media{name: "@campaign[cover]", type: "file"}/
        .form-group
            .col-sm-offset-3.col-sm-6
                %button.form-button.btn-large.btn-green.btn#campaign-submit{type: "submit"}
                    Set up Campaign
```

And this is my create method

```
def create
    campaign = params[:@campaign]
    campaign['added_by_email'] = current_user.email
    @campaign = ThemedCampaign.create(campaign)

    if @campaign.save
        img_attr =  params[:@campaign]['cover']
        image = Campaign.new img_attr
        @campaign.cover = image
        Resque.enqueue(ImageQueue,image.id)
        #render :json => image.to_jq_upload.to_json
    end

    redirect_to '/admin/themecampaign'
end
```

I have created a seperate uploader for this,

```
# encoding: utf-8

class CampaignUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
    storage :file
    # storage :fog

    before :cache, :save_original_filename

    # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
    # For images you might use something like this:
    def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg png)
    end

    # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
    # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
    def store_dir
        "uploads/campaigns/#{model.id}/"
    end

end
```

And this is my campaign modal, which hold the image

```
class Campaign
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Mongoid::Paranoia
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    mount_uploader :cover, CampaignUploader
end
```

Now when I upload the form I keep getting an `undefined method`empty?' for #

```
> NoMethodError - undefined method `empty?' for
> #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000109968c50>:    () Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/mongoid-bc72426681d5/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:21:in
> `process_attributes'    ()
> Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/mongoid-bc72426681d5/lib/mongoid/document.rb:111:in `block in initialize'    ()
> Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/mongoid-bc72426681d5/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:84:in
> `_building'    ()
> Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/mongoid-bc72426681d5/lib/mongoid/document.rb:105:in `initialize'   actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:104:in `initialize'  
> app/controllers/themed_campaign_controller.rb:57:in `new'  
> app/controllers/themed_campaign_controller.rb:57:in `create'
```

Essentially, this blows up while trying to call Campaign.new with the image attributes. I thought the image field was nil but when I inspected the img_attr from the server, I noticed the uploaded file was present and the temp field was corretly pointing to a local copy.

When I dug deeper, I noticed the the `cover` filed in my themed_controller was invalid.

> ```
> MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 INSERT       database=mangoweb_development collection=themed_campaigns
> ```
>
> documents=[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53ba605c5661731da8060000'),
>   "campaign_title"=>"Test campaign", "campaign_description"=>"Test
>   campaign desciption", "live_story_ids"=>["53a9b3e5566173146e030000",
>   "5343eafc5661731195030000", "5343eacc566173117f030000",
>   "5343eadf5661731189030000"], "valid_from"=>2014-07-07 00:00:00 UTC,
>   "valid_till"=>2014-07-22 00:00:00 UTC,
>   "cover"=>"#",
>   "added_by_email"=>"xxxxxxxxx",
>   "campaign_sane_title"=>"Test-campaign", "updated_at"=>2014-07-07
>   08:54:52 UTC, "created_at"=>2014-07-07 08:54:52 UTC}] flags=[]
>                                COMMAND      database=mangoweb_development command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1}
>   runtime: 11.9600ms
>       #

What am I doing wrong here?Why is the value of cover is a String version of the uploaded Object reference, instead of the file values, and why the Image not getting created?

I've been over this issue for the last 2 days, and have looked at various references. I know, I must be doing something very silly, but I'm not able to get it.

Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form instance object to easily handle this

Change

```
 form_for(@campaign, validate: true, :html => {:multipart => true}) do
```

to

```
 form_for(@campaign, validate: true, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
```

and use `f` while referencing the form fields

```
%textarea.form-input{ name: "@campaign[campaign_description]", placeholder: "Campaign Description",  required: "", value: ""}
```

should be changed to

```
f.text_area :campaign_description, placeholder: "Campaign Description",  required: "", value: ""
```

and for the file field

```
f.file_field :cover
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks for the offline support. The issue was with my modal. I had completely forgotten about defining the embedded relationship. Once I did that, everything worked fine. Thanks again for the support.